# When opening multiple reports in acReportView mode the first one is opened, and the rest are canceled and throws error 2501

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need to open 4 different reports with a button press but I have run into an issue where the report open command is getting canceled in its second doCmd.OpenReport line. This is

```
    If con1 = False Then
        DoCmd.OpenReport "cust1", acViewReport, , "[comboID] = '" & CStr(custTicketGroupingID.Value) & "' AND [customer] = '" & CStr(Me.cmbCust1.Value) & "'"
    End If
    If con2 = False Then
        DoCmd.OpenReport "cust2", acViewReport, , "[comboID] = '" & CStr(custTicketGroupingID.Value) & "' AND [customer] = '" & CStr(Me.cmbCust2.Value) & "'"
    End If
    If con3 = False Then
        DoCmd.OpenReport "cust3", acViewReport, , "[comboID] = '" & CStr(custTicketGroupingID.Value) & "' AND [customer] = '" & CStr(Me.cmbCust3.Value) & "'"
    End If
    DoCmd.OpenReport "combinedCustomerReport", acViewReport, , "[comboID] = '" & CStr(custTicketGroupingID.Value) & "'"
```

my code for handling the opening of these reports.

I've tried several things already. I need it to open in acReportView mode because I have buttons on the report that the user will need to be able to use, however, I have gotten some improvement by switching to open on print preview it still hits the 2501 error on the third reports execution however it is an improvement from the previous one only being able to print one.

Comment: It works for me and opens 4 reports in a row flawlessly. The error number 2501 is unspecific. Try to compact and repair the db (front-end and back-end if avail).

Answer (score 1):

Repairing and compacting the database fixed the issue.

Thanks, @Olivier Jacot-Descombes for bringing this to my attention.